# SX1276 LoRa - Implicit mode - Not knowing PayloadLength at reception

Tags: lora, sx1276

I'm trying to use SX1276 in Implicit Header Mode, and extracting the `PayloadLength` after `ValidHeader` interrupts. The first byte is the payload length. The reception works OK 80% of the time. For the rest of the time, it just reads random data.

#### Config:

- BW: 125khz or 500Khz - no influence
- AFC BW: 250khz
- CR: 4/8 or 4/5 - no influence
- I have taken into account the Errata recommendations for SF6.
  For Explicit Header mode, SF7, its 100% reliable

#### Valid Header IRQ:

```c
void RF_IRQ1_handler() {
    if (RF_module.config.modulation == Lora) {
        RF_write_reg(Lora_RegFifoRxBaseAddr, 0x00);
        RF_write_reg(Lora_RegPayloadLength, 0xFF); //Not to trigger TxDone based on last transmission
        uint8_t rx = RF_read_reg(Lora_RegFifoRxByteAddr);
        while (rx == RF_read_reg(Lora_RegFifoRxByteAddr)) { //It waits for 4ms for data to be written to FIFO
        }
        RF_write_reg(Lora_RegPayloadLength, RF_read_reg(Lora_RegFifo));         
    }
}
```

How can I improve my transfer rate?

Answer (score 3):

After trial & error I found the issue: modem is sensitive to preamble length (I was using the minimum of 6). With preamble length=7 transmission is 100% reliable.